# Tensorflow slicing based on variable

Tags: python, tensorflow

I've found that indexing still is an open issue in tensorflow [(#206)](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/206), so I'm wondering what I could use as a workaround at the moment. I want to index/slice a row/column of a matrix based on a variable that changes for every training example.

What I've tried so far:

1. Slicing based on placeholder (doesn't work)

The following (working) code slices based on a fixed number.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

x = tf.placeholder("float")
y = tf.slice(x,[0],[1])

#initialize
init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init)

#run
result = sess.run(y, feed_dict={x:[1,2,3,4,5]})
print(result)
```

However, it seems that I can't simply replace one of these fixed numbers with a tf.placeholder. The following code gives me the error *"TypeError: List of Tensors when single Tensor expected."*

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

x = tf.placeholder("float")
i = tf.placeholder("int32")
y = tf.slice(x,[i],[1])

#initialize
init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init)

#run
result = sess.run(y, feed_dict={x:[1,2,3,4,5],i:0})
print(result)
```

This sounds like the brackets around *[i]* are too much, but removing them  doesn't help either. How to use a placeholder/variable as index?

2. Slicing based on python variable (doesn't backprop/update properly)

I've also tried using a normal python variable as index. This does not lead to an error, but the network doesn't learn anything while training. I suppose because the changing variable is not properly registered, the graph is malformed and updates don't work?

3. Slicing via one-hot vector + multiplication (works, but is slow)

One workaround I found is using a one-hot vector. Making a one-hot vector in numpy, passing this using a placeholder, then doing the slicing via matrix multiplication. This works, but is quite slow.

Any ideas how to efficiently slice/index based on a variable?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Slicing based on a placeholder should work just fine. It looks like you are running into a type error, due to some subtle issues of shapes and types. Where you have the following:

```
x = tf.placeholder("float")
i = tf.placeholder("int32")
y = tf.slice(x,[i],[1])
```

...you should instead have:

```
x = tf.placeholder("float")
i = tf.placeholder("int32")
y = tf.slice(x,i,[1])
```

...and then you should feed `i` as `[0]` in the call to `sess.run()`.

To make this a little clearer, I would recommend rewriting the code as follows:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None])  # 1-D tensor
i = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[1])
y = tf.slice(x, i, [1])

#initialize
init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init)

#run
result = sess.run(y, feed_dict={x: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], i: [0]})
print(result)
```

The additional `shape` arguments to the `tf.placeholder` op help to ensure that the values you feed have the appropriate shapes, and also that TensorFlow will raise an error if the shapes are not correct.

Comment: It gave the following error:
    ValueError: Shape () must have rank 1

Comment: Ah yes, TensorFlow became more strict about the difference between scalars and length-1 vectors since I posted this. Updated the answer to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an extra dimension, this works.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

def reorder0(e, i, length):
    '''
    e: a two dimensional tensor
    i: a one dimensional int32 tensor, of shape (e.shape[0])
    returns: a tensor of the same shape as e, where the jth entry is entry i[j] from e
    '''
    return tf.concat(
        [ tf.expand_dims( e[i[j],:], axis=0)  for j in range(length) ],
        axis=0
    )

e = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(2,3,5), name='e' )  # sentences, words, embedding
i = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=(2,3), name='i' ) # for each word, index of parent
p = tf.concat(
    [ tf.expand_dims(reorder0(e[k,:,:], i[k,:], 3), axis=0)  for k in range(2) ],
    axis=0,
    name='p'
)

#initialize
init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init)

#run
result = sess.run(p, feed_dict={
    e: [ 
        ( (1.0,1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4),(2.0,2.1,2.2,2.3,2.4),(3.0,3.1,3.2,3.3,3.4) ), 
        ( (21.0,21.1,21.2,21.3,21.4),(22.0,22.1,22.2,22.3,22.4),(23.0,23.1,23.2,23.3,23.4) ),  
    ], 
    i: [ (1,1,1), (2,0,2)]
})
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the sizes are not known when building the model, use TensorArray.

```
e = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(3,5) )  # words, embedding
i = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=(3) ) # for each word, index of parent
#p = reorder0(e, i, 3)
a = tf.TensorArray(
    tf.float32, 
    size=e.get_shape()[0],
    dynamic_size=True,
    infer_shape= True,
    element_shape=e.get_shape()[1],
    clear_after_read = False
)


#initialize
init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init)

#run
result = sess.run(
    a.unstack(e).gather(i), 
    feed_dict={
        e: ( (1.0,1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4),(2.0,2.1,2.2,2.3,2.4),(3.0,3.1,3.2,3.3,3.4) ),
            #( (21.0,21.1,21.2,21.3,21.4),(22.0,22.1,22.2,22.3,22.4),(23.0,23.1,23.2,23.3,23.4) ),  
        i: (2,0,2)
    }
)
print(result)
```